# TF2 padded_batch on supervised dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.x

## Problem setting

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings). The tutorial first loads a supervised dataset (using `tfds.load` with `as_supervised=True`):

```py
(train_data, test_data), info = tfds.load(
    'imdb_reviews/subwords8k', 
    split = (tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST), 
    with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

Then the tutorial suggests to shuffle and pad the dataset like this:

> Movie reviews can be different lengths. We will use the `padded_batch` method to standardize the lengths of the reviews.

```py
train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10)
test_batches = test_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10)
```

... but unfortunately the [`padded_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) method needs an extra argument that the tutorial seems to have forgotten:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imdb_reviews.py", line 14, in <module>
    train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10)
TypeError: padded_batch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'padded_shapes'
```

## Important assumption

Although the errors stack says that `padded_shapes` is the missing argument, from the tutorial I think it's fair to deduce that the missing argument is in fact `batch_size` (that should precede `padded_shapes`).

## What I have tried

I thought this might be easily fixed like this:

```py
batch_sz = 100 # arbitrary number
train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(batch_sz, ([10],[None]))
test_batches = test_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(batch_sz, ([10],[None]))
```

... but my solution is apparently wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imdb_reviews.py", line 15, in <module>
    train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(batch_sz, ([10],[None]))
  File "/home/ggiuffre/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2298, in padded_batch
    batch_size, padded_shapes, padding_values, drop_remainder))
  File "/home/ggiuffre/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1481, in padded_batch
    drop_remainder)
  File "/home/ggiuffre/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3813, in __init__
    _padded_shape_to_tensor(padded_shape, input_component_shape))
  File "/home/ggiuffre/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3741, in _padded_shape_to_tensor
    % (padded_shape_as_shape, input_component_shape))
ValueError: The padded shape (None,) is not compatible with the corresponding input component shape ().
```

Substituting `None` with `()` gives me `ValueError: Padded shape [()] must be a 1-D tensor of tf.int64 values, but its shape was (1, 0).`

Substituting `None` with `1` gives me `ValueError: The padded shape (1,) is not compatible with the corresponding input component shape ().`

## Problem

What value should I give to the `padded_shapes` argument? Or, more generally, what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this blog. https://medium.com/@a.ydobon/tensorflow-2-0-word-embeddings-part3-964b2b9caf94

It recommends

```
padded_shapes = ([None],())
train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10,padded_shapes=padded_shapes)
test_batches = test_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10,padded_shapes=padded_shapes)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This also works fine

```py
batch_sz = 100 # arbitrary number
train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000)
test_batches = test_data.shuffle(1000)

train_batches = train_batches.padded_batch(batch_sz, train_batches.output_shapes)
test_batches = test_batches.padded_batch(batch_sz, test_batches.output_shapes)
```

Than you can define your LSTM layers and fit train_batches ,test_batches

Comment: This is, according to the docs & a warning printed at runtime, deprecated https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/data/Dataset